# How to get jpeg or pngs from .tfrec

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I am pytorch user and i encounter data that contain **.tfrec** i want to convert them to jpeg/png format so that i can read it in my pytorch code. 
I have search the google but found nothing. 
Any help how pytorch user handle tfre

if i read them directly like

```
import torchvision.transforms as T
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
transform_train = T.Compose([
    T.RandomCrop(128, padding_mode="reflect"),
    T.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    T.ToTensor()
])
train_ds = ImageFolder(
    root=path_to_folder,
    transform=transform_train
)
```

it will through err

> RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders Supported extensions are:

> .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp